# How can dipole in two different subject have different directions?

Tags: vectors, dipole

dipole in chemistry has a direction in the flow of electron i.e. from positive to negative whereas in physics it is from negative to position why ?

Comment: Are you talking about electron flow inside or outside of a cell?

Comment: In case of chemistry I am talking about the flow between two compounds , and in case of physics I am talking the case of our common dipole that we usually study under electrostatics

Comment: In physics, a dipole is two equal but opposite charges with some distance between them. A free electron in the vicinity would be repelled by the negative charge and attracted toward the positive charge.  I'm not clear on what flow your are referring to in chemistry. I do know that in a cell, a chemical reaction takes electrons from the positive terminal and puts them on the negative terminal.

Comment: In chemistry if we study about ionic compounds then electrons flow from cation to anion hence it's direction is given as +ve to -ve and this entire system can be said as a dipole , as on one end we have a +ve charge and on the other end we have a -ve charge on the atom , similarly if I talk about the dipole that we deal in physics under electrostatics even that is a combination of a negative and a positive change ,but in case of physics there the direction is considered to be from -ve to +ve , right ,this is the place I am getting confused as in how can same thing be different in 2 cases.